# R: Sort 2-D array in ascending numerical order by attributes

Tags: r, sorting

I have created an array "duration" of time-durations using the `tapply` function in R.  The attributes associated with the array vector are "character" class and I believe this is why they are sorting as `"1" "10" "100" "2" "20" "200"...`example below in code.

The aforementioned attributes are associated with a Trip Number and I would like to sort by this number in ascending order (1,2,3...).  I have attempted various attacks using `order`, `sort`, converting to `data.frame`, etc. but have been unsuccessful.  Please help!

My code is below.

---

```
tripDur <- function (aDate) {
    difftime(max(aDate), min(aDate), units = "hours")   
}

tmp<- tapply(gps$D_DATE, gps$trip, tripDur)
duration <- tmp; duration

> duration
         1         10        100        101        102        103        104        105 
14.8155556  4.6188889  1.6166667 15.9366667 27.4000000 18.1200000 16.8522222 16.9066667

> str(duration)
num [1:158(1d)] 14.82 4.62 1.62 15.94 27.4 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:158] "1" "10" "100" "101" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something along the lines of this.

```
> my.vec <- letters[1:5]
> names(my.vec) <- c("1", "10", "5", "100", "13")
> my.vec
  1  10   5 100  13 
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" 
> my.vec[order(as.numeric(names(my.vec)))]
  1   5  10  13 100 
"a" "c" "b" "e" "d"
```